# Insert WHERE if condition into class mysql query.

Tags: php, mysql

Hello How I can convert the followin query so I don't have the error given: Catchable fatal error:

**`Object of class pagination could not be converted to string`**

```
$paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM properties WHERE 1', $options);


            if (!empty($sector)) { $paginate .= " AND sector = :sector"; }
            if (!empty($property_type))  { $paginate .= " AND property_type = :property_type"; }
            if (!empty($contract))  { $paginate .= " AND contract = :contract"; }
            if (!empty($minimum_price))  { $paginate .= " AND price BETWEEN :minimum_price AND :maximum_price"; }
            if (!empty($m2_from))  { $paginate .= " AND m2 BETWEEN :m2_from AND :m2_until"; }
            if (!empty($contract))  { $paginate .= " AND bedrooms = :bedrooms"; }
```

Comment: 1 is what here `SELECT * FROM properties WHERE 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$paginate** is a object variable of the class  pagination, so its variable type is object. I would build the query first then create the object.

So what we are doing here, is creating a string variable of your query and assign it with the defaut `SELECT` query. Then we run the `if statements` and after that we build it, that way you are not trying to add a string to an object type.

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE 1";

        if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= " AND sector = :sector"; }
        if (!empty($property_type))  { $query.= " AND property_type = :property_type"; }
        if (!empty($contract))  { $query .= " AND contract = :contract"; }
        if (!empty($minimum_price))  { $query .= " AND price BETWEEN :minimum_price AND :maximum_price"; }
        if (!empty($m2_from))  { $query .= " AND m2 BETWEEN :m2_from AND :m2_until"; }
        if (!empty($contract))  { $query .= " AND bedrooms = :bedrooms"; }

$paginate = new pagination($page, $query, $options);
```

**Edit 1**

Also your `SELECT` query is incorrect. You're missing the column name after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: what do you suggest about column missing, Usuallly it is working when I am not using bind values, but in this case is not selecting the proper results.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select? Because that is what's meant to be in that query. so `SELECT * FROM properties WHERE some_column_name = 1`.

Comment: it is a search form, in you choose sector from drop down menu select the whole row from table properties where sector='1'

Comment: So after the `WHERE` clause put `sector = 1`.

Comment: yes but there are different inputs, so depends on which input send value it selects. this why the if's are, you might have sector = 2 and contract = 3. the actual number comes from the bind values from the form post.

Comment: @JohnSiniger then just leave it as `SELECT * FROM properties` then the `if statements` should set the value anyway.